# Android status bar - can it be transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, statusbar

Can Android status bar  be transparent like in iOS? I want it to blend into activity like on iOS. Can it be done and if yes - how?

EDIT: Just to clarify I need to make status bar transparent, not action bar, and yes I know I can completely hide it - but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Are you creating an application or modifying the framework?

Comment: @k_wisniewski can you solved this? if yes then share your idea. It's very very urgent to me.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't make the system status bar transparent, and [shouldn't try to do so in an attempt to mimic iOS](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html):

> Don't mimic UI elements from other platforms

Comment: I was asked to do so by my customer - personally I see no point in showing status bar in this particular app

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4 KitKit now allows translucent status and navigation bars:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI

For example, you can set the theme as Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your activity fullscreen so you won't see the status bar.

Like this  :

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Or set a theme like this

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can completely hide this, but I want it to be where it is and just change background like on iOS so that it looks transparent

Answer (score -1):

It can be done.

Take a look at the following library which basically implements a fading action bar, starting from fully transparent.

https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

Comment: I was asking about status bar, not the action bar.

Comment: My bad. No there's no way to do it. The status bar is part of a system app named SystemUI. The only thing you can do is hide it as @Torrent-lookup mentioned on the other answer.